# Upgrade from Neo4J 3.3.3 Community to Neo4J 3.5 Enterprise

Tags: neo4j

I currently have Neo4J 3.3.3 community installed on the server and I want to upgrade to Neo4J 3.5. I have a few questions to clarify before I do that:

1. Will it be sufficient to simply install the new database and to point it to the existing community datastore as well as uncommenting the `dbms.allow_upgrade=true`? Or should there be any additional measures taken?
2. Does it make sense to upgrade directly to  Neo4J 4 or better to upgrade to 3.5 first?
3. Do I need to reinstall the APOC tools for the new version?
4. How does the admin in the enterprise version work? I recall that the enterprise version comes with some kind of extra interface. Is it available via Linux? Do I access it via the browser `:7474` (or whatever my Neo4J port is)?

Thank you!

Comment: from my memory (neo4j engineers here might have better answers) 
1. may not work even with the setting you mention here.
2. this may require input from neo4j engineers. upgrade to a major version change may not be smooth from my past experience.
To be safe, Why dont you,
install a separate enterprise edition using vagrant/virtualbox instance, install neo4j enterprise,  import data first? 
You may need to do a backup  from community edition , then restore it into the enterprise edition.. 
See this link - https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup/restoring/

Comment: I have done this type of migration in the past. From community edition with lower version to Enterprise edition higher version. It worked just with `dbms.allow_upgrade=true` . I am not sure about Neo4j 4. I would suggest you install an enterprise version then before starting Neo4j copy the old database folder to the new Neo4j's Database folder and check if it starts successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the questions:

First, you need to upgrade to the latest 3.3.latest and only then to 3.5.latest.

1. You need to copy the database (in `/database/` folder) either manually or using the `neo4j-admin dump` command as well as the `dbms` folder with user management. Leave a backup somewhere else. Then uncomment the `dbms.allow_upgrade=true` and launch the DB
2. First to the latest version of 3.5, then to Neo4j 4?
3. Yes. The appropriate APOC for 4.0
4. The admin is accessible at :7474 (or the port you choose for insecure bolt). Desktop version can be downloaded separately.